# Is There A Library of Public API Swagger Definitions?

Tags: swagger, raml

So I've been building a service that taps into popular APIs around the web and I've found Swagger to be a huge asset to the project. Instead of writing a ton of custom code that is difficult to maintain, I've been able to use Swagger definitions to dynamically create all my requests to the public APIs our service supports.

This has been working well for ~1 year, but we want to continue adding services to our platform and we ended up trading one maintenance burden for another. While there are a lot of public APIs out there, not many of them are nicely packaged in a computer consumable form such as Swagger.

I was wondering if anyone knew of a central location on the internet where a library of Swagger, RAML, API Blueprint, etc are stored.

If such a thing doesn't yet exist it probably should.

Comment: On APIs.io, the search engine for APIs you can list all the APIs that have a swagger definitions like this http://apis.io/api/apis?swagger=true

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing yet - probably your closest thing would be ProgrammableWeb (just a generic API directory), PublicAPIs (another directory), and APImatic.io (they pull in APIs from several different sources), but there is no set collection of API Blueprint, Swagger, and RAML APIs as these are all open specs.

However, you may be able to contact the different API providers (API Blueprint - Apiary, RAML - MuleSoft, and Swagger - Apigee/ 3Scale) to see if they can provide you with the APIs created in their tools.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Mike. Great information!